# environmental variables vs. global variables

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, global-variables

I am pretty new to shell scripting and python. While I was reading the materials, I saw the term "environmental variable" in shell and "global variable" in python.   I kind of feel these two words mean the same but not sure. Can anyone explain their difference in more details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A global variable only exists inside your script. An environment variable exists in your environment.

Comment: global variable: variable defined in upper scope. environment variable: OS environment variable, like PATH, accessed through `os.environ`

Comment: Thank you the clarification.

Comment: In general, "What's the difference between X and Y" questions aren't very useful for programmers. Most of the time, X and Y *aren't meaningfully related*, so it really boils down to a vague request to explain X and also explain Y. That would be two questions, neither of which is specific enough for Stack Overflow. Even when there is an important connection, the real underlying question is typically "how do I choose which one to use?", or "I already understand X; how can I understand Y by analogy (or the other way around)"? Both of these require a more specific context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't mean the same. "global" is a programming language idea, "environment variable" is an operating system idea. So, they're not really related, and conceptually quite different!

Since you now know that, and both terms are easily researchable ("environment variable" on wikipedia, global variable on the Python.org language tutorial), I'm not going to write an introduction into two completely unrelated topics here – I simply couldn't put it any better.

Note that as Python beginner, you will *not* have to deal with explicitly global variables often. In fact, `global` is usually a keyword you should avoid, it often is a sign that you forgot to correctly think of what goes in and out of a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a python beginner.

Basically, environmental variables are good only used in their "containers" (i.e. functions, classes etc) and global variables work throughout the script.

Comment: You've confused local variables with environmental variables. A local variable is what you have described, an environment variable on the operating system.